# Custom value for list_display item on Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In a model I have a subtitle field, which is populated with `None` if no value exists for the field for the given object.

Is there any way to display the value to something custom (like `Not Available` or `Not Applicable` than just displaying `(None)`

field

```
sub_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

admin

```
 list_display = 'sub_title',
```

[image]

PS: I want `None` in the database, while a custom value just on admin panel.

thanks

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`list_display` can accept a callable, so you can do this:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('get_sub_title',)

    def get_sub_title(self, obj):
        if obj.sub_title:
            return obj.sub_title
        else:
            return 'Not Available'

    get_sub_title.short_description = 'Subtitle'
```

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) provide several other options for providing a callable.

Answer (score 13):

It would be better if you use **`empty_value_display`**

> [empty_value_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.empty_value_display) 
>   This attribute overrides the default display value for record’s fields that are empty (None, empty string, etc.). The default value is - (a dash).

```
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('sub_title',)
    sub_title.empty_value_display = 'Not Available'
```

This is for `django >= 1.9`